# Split single column data frame in R at NA

Tags: r

I have a large data set that I want to split into individual units.  Right now, these unit barriers are marked by NA, but how do I split them?  Sample set:

```
df=matrix(c(1,2,3,4,NA,6,7,8,NA,10,11,12),ncol=1,byrow=TRUE)
```

gives us

```
       [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    2
 [3,]    3
 [4,]    4
 [5,]   NA
 [6,]    6
 [7,]    7
 [8,]    8
 [9,]   NA
[10,]    10
[11,]    11
[12,]    12
```

I would like these three stored in separate variables, such that

```
a
      [,1]
 [1,]    1
 [2,]    2
 [3,]    3
 [4,]    4
b
      [,1]
 [1,]    6
 [2,]    7
 [3,]    8
c
      [,1]
 [1,]    10
 [2,]    11
 [3,]    12
```

Does this make sense?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't sure if by "data set" you meant a true matrix or a data.frame. Here's a data.frame example, a matrix would be similar

```
df <- data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4,NA,6,7,8,NA,10,11,12))
gg <- ifelse(is.na(df$a),NA, cumsum(is.na(df$a)))
split(df, gg)
```

We just use `gg` as a new variable to count up every time we see an NA so we can divide the sections into groups. We also retain the NA values to drop them for the splitting. And finally `split()` with this new categorical variable does what we want.

```
$`0`
  a
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4

$`1`
  a
6 6
7 7
8 8

$`2`
    a
10 10
11 11
12 12
```

Comment: This is great, thanks!  To assign these results to other variables, would a<-(split(df,gg)$"0") and so on be appropriate?  It may not be the most efficient, but I understand what it's doing now.

Comment: I wouldn't split them unless you had a really, really good reason to. Working with a named list like that is way easier than a much of variables. But if yiou really wanted to , something like `list2env(setNames(split(df,gg), letters[0:max(gg, na.rm=T)+1]), envir=globalenv())` would be more direct maybe.

Answer (score 2):

One line solution using `split` and `cumsum` after removing missing values:

```
 split(df[!is.na(df)],cumsum(is.na(df))[!is.na(df)])
$`0`
[1] 1 2 3 4

$`1`
[1] 6 7 8

$`2`
[1] 10 11 12
```